# SQL - Field outputted as a proportion by dividing by frequency of another field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to show a 'proportion' field for website user data where proportion will be the measure of how much a certain data source contributes to their conversion (whatever that may be, it is irrelevant).

This is the kind of output I'm hoping to achieve with SQL:

```
Month  | ID | Country | Data Source |Proportion
Jan-15 | 1  | UK      |   GA        |    0.5
Jan-15 | 1  | UK      |   Omniture  |    0.5
Jan-15 | 2  | France  |   GA        |     1
Jan-15 | 3  | Germany |   GA        |    0.25
Jan-15 | 3  | Germany |   Omniture  |    0.25
Jan-15 | 3  | Germany |   Email     |    0.25
Jan-15 | 3  | Germany |   Moz       |    0.25
Feb-15 | 1  | UK      |   GA        |    0.5
Feb-15 | 1  | UK      |   Omniture  |    0.5
Feb-15 | 2  | France  |   Omniture  |    0.5
Feb-15 | 2  | France  |   GA        |    0.5
Feb-15 | 3  | Germany |   Omniture  |    0.33
Feb-15 | 3  | Germany |   Email     |    0.33
Feb-15 | 3  | Germany |   Moz       |    0.33
Mar-15 | 1  | UK      |   Omniture  |    0.5
Mar-15 | 1  | UK      |   GA        |    0.5
Mar-15 | 2  | France  |   Omniture  |    0.5
Mar-15 | 2  | France  |   Email     |    0.5
```

And this is the SQL that I am currently working and failing with:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(registrationDate), country, DataSource, 1/COUNT(ID)
FROM
    data_table
WHERE
    registrationDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    MONTH(registrationDate), ID
```

This is only giving one instance of the proportion. Using the example above, user with ID 1 in January will only have one record with Proportion = 0.5.

Any help in showing this proportion value correctly shared between data sources would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide *sample* data (the id columns are confusing).  Also, tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment before - how do I tag with the database I'm using? Very new to this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the results with the original data.  Here is a method using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT dt.*, ddt.value
FROM data_table dt JOIN
     (SELECT MONTH(registrationDate) as mon, ID, 
             1.0/COUNT(applicantId) as value
      FROM data_table
      WHERE registrationDate IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY MONTH(registrationDate), ID
     ) ddt
     ON ddt.id = dt.id AND 
        ddt.mon = MONTH(dt.registrationDate);
```

Your question has `ID`, `ApplicationId`, and `RegistrationId` sprinkled throughout.  I'm not sure what the right column(s) to use are.

EDIT:

To include year (which really is a good idea in all cases):

```
SELECT dt.*, ddt.value
FROM data_table dt JOIN
     (SELECT YEAR(registrationDate) as yyyy, MONTH(registrationDate) as mon, ID, 
             1.0/COUNT(applicantId) as value
      FROM data_table
      WHERE registrationDate IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY YEAR(registrationDate), MONTH(registrationDate), ID
     ) ddt
     ON ddt.id = dt.id AND 
        ddt.mon = MONTH(dt.registrationDate) AND
        ddt.yyyy = YEAR(dt.registrationDate);
```

Comment: Cheers! That's great. Yes, that's sloppy of me - they all should be the same ID

Comment: Hey again Gordon. I've since realised here are multiple years that my data set contains so grouping by just the month part may share out credits regardless of the year...is there a way to join and group by the month and year together without using the whole date value? So above we have MONTH(registrationDate) - is there a MONTHYEAR(registrationDate) type of function that could be used? Thanks